# How to redirect www.domain.com/subfolder/ to www.domain.com/subfolder/blog.html using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

How to redirect `www.domain.com/subfolder/` to `www.domain.com/subfolder/blog.html`, because I cannot have index.html. So that's why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch ^/subfolder/?$ http://www.domain.com/subfolder/blog.html
```

This will redirect `/subfolder/` to  `http://www.domain.com/subfolder/blog.html` .

Comment: Sorry not working, its redirecting to 404page. What would be the problem ?

Comment: Its working here. Where are adding this? Is the htaccess enabled on your server?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `/subfolder/.htaccess` if it doesn't exist and add this line at the top:

```
DirectoryIndex blog.html
```

Comment: can you explain it little bit more.

Comment: This loads `blog.html` by default when requesting `/subfolder/`. Test it out and let me know

Comment: here `/subfolder/` refers `www.domain.com/blog/` right ?

Comment: This is to serve your requirement of `How to redirect www.domain.com/subfolder/ to www.domain.com/subfolder/blog.html`

Comment: So i have to create `.htaccess` file inside `www.domain.com/blog/` this path right ?

Comment: Thank you. I will give a try.